# How can I treat a logical block as a text object in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugins

Here's a situation I'm in every day:

```
0  .outer_selector {
1  
2   .inner_selector {
3     margin: 0;
4     padding: 0;
5
6     input { display: none; }
7   }
8
9  }
```

Now I want to cut and paste the `.inner_selector` somewhere else. How can I do it? I can't figure out any way to quickly delete the logical `.inner_selector` block *with* it's surrounding whitespace; i.e., the equivalent to `dap` but for this brace-delimited block. Here are various ideas, in increasing order of gnarliness. (`ai` and `ii` mappings are via the [vim-indent-obj](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) plugin.)

1. `3Gdai`. This almost works but leaves the closing brace for the `.inner_selector` block where it is.
2. `2Gdai`. No good; this deletes the whole `.outer_selector` block.
3. `2Gdii`. This deletes the correct block, but not the surrounding whitespace (i.e., the equivalent of `dip` instead of `dap`).
4. `2Gf{d%`. Go to `{` with `f{`, delete to matching brace (`d%`). This deletes the text from the brace on line 2 to its matching brace, but leaves the text "`.inner_selector`".
5. `2Gf{v%okd`. Starts same as (4), then jump to top of selected text (`o`), extend by one line upward (`k`), and delete (`d`). Same as (3), above.
6. `3Gvaikojjd`. Select text, select one additional line upward (`k`), jump to bottom of selected region (`o`), select two lines down (`jj`), delete (`d`). This works.

I can define a keyboard mapping for the last one and be done with it, but before I do that I want to be sure I'm not missing something here. Since it's such a common code construct in many languages, I'm surprised it's this difficult to treat `text { /* multiple lines /* }` as a text object, or that there's no plugin for it.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a text object for braces, it's `B` or `{` or `}`.](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/)

If you go to the whitespace in `.outer-selector` but out of `.inner-selector` you can see it select everything with `Vi{` to select everything inside the `.outer-selector` braces.

I can also hit just the `.inner-selector` parts by running `Vi{` inside `.inner-selector` and then hitting `V` again to force it to take all the full lines. This won't get you the whitespace around `.inner-selector` but I thought it might be of interest as well.

Comment: Thanks Camilo! I didn't know about hitting V again to select the full line -- cool trick. (Though I only got it to work with `va{V`, not `vi{V`.) You're right, the first method works perfectly in my example; however, it won't work if I have multiple `.inner_selectors` and only want to delete one.